# RelativeLayout create button at a dynamic position

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

[image]

I am working on a project that involves painting on images.

To delete the unwanted lines or curves i have to draw a border and X button to delete it.

I have a relative layout where i have the freehand drawing canvas. on edit mode i should make them as u see in the pic, where i have to create button on a varying x,y positions.

i am confused how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.
Jana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing this manually rather than using the `Button` widget. Override the `onTouchEvent` on the view holding your painting and use `MotionEvent.getX` and `MotionEvent.getY` in combination with `MotionEvent.getAction` to determine behaviour when the user touches the 'button'. Skipping widget creation will improve performance and open up doors to other types of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the deprecated AbsoluteLayout container for this or keep the RelativeLayout and use layoutMargins to set the location of the buttons. The former is the route you should take despite the container being deprecated as the later breaks the layout paradigm by misusing margins...

You should keep in mind that there are a variety of devices with different screen sizes and setting explicit, pixel based locations is going to be awkward.